# Operator WHERE LIKE % in Python/Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

i have a script below in python using library pandas:

```
        search = input('enter your name')

        df1 = pd.read_excel('base.xlsx')

        check = df1[df1['.NAME.'].str.contains(search)]

        if check.size > 0:
            for index, row in df1.iterrows():
                if search in row['.NAME.']:

                  print('FOUND')
        else:
            print('NOT FOUND.')
```

The user types in the name in the input, the script checks the base.xlsx, if it returns any records, it compares if the typed name is in the base.

If the user types the full name or the name in the correct order (example: MICHAEL JOSEPH JACKSON or just MICHAEL JOSEPH (ordered name)), the script is working correctly, but if the user types only MICHAEL JACKSON (FIRST AND LAST NAME) for the same person, it not find.

In SQL there is LIKE % where you can get the name in any order it is typed (example: `SELECT * FROM BASE WHERE NAME LIKE %FIRST_NAME% AND NAME LIKE %SECOND_NAME% AND NAME LIKE %LAST_NAME`), in python/pandas is it possible to do something similar?

how check name in any order entered?

Comment: Use a regular expression. `michael.*jackson`

Comment: great, using regular expression works. thanks.